# Задача из E-Olymp:Площадь и объем пирамиды

Tags: c, математика, геометрия, олимпиада

[Ссылка на задачу](https://www.e-olymp.com/ru/problems/948)

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <math.h>  
int main(void)  
{  
float p,d,H,h,S,V;  
scanf("%f %f",&d,&p);  
S=d*d + 2*d*sqrt(p*p-(d*d)/4);  
H=sqrt(p*p - (d*d)/2);  
V=d*d*H/3;  
printf("%.3f %.3f",S,V);  
}
```

Много раз перепроверял,ошибку не вижу вообще.Помогите!

Comment: Интересно, откуда вообще это стремление использовать `float`, а не `double` ? Это преподы говорят, что так лучше или почему? Вот это, `while(!feof(file))`, работа в функциями с переменным числом аргументов через указатели, а не `stdarg`... Что это? (@Stan, это не к вам, это просто философски :) уж очень часто попадается).

Comment: Очень хорошее замечание.Просто было сказано с точностью до тысячных вычислять и я привык для подобных случаев использовать float.И нет,это не преподы говорят,а в Интернете увидел.@Harry

Comment: @Harry Возможно такие вопросы тут не задают,но других путей нет,да и очень интересно.Дело в том,что Вы очень хорошо разбираетесь в вычислительной математике и мне интересно какое у Вас образование и кто Вы по профессии?       P.S Мне всегда нравится Ваш статус,я тоже считаю,что настоящий программист-это математик!!!

Comment: Меня как образец брать не надо, меня жизнь помотала капитально :) Диплом - радиофизик, дисер - по прошковой металлургии, так что, как я писал в информации о себе - "программирование у меня хобби, а не профессия"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оценим может ли тип `float` выдать нужную точность в этой задаче. В условиях сказано что сторона основания и длина бокового ребра не превосходят `100`. Тогда площадь поверхности и объём будут `27320.508` и `235702.250` соответственно. Я воспользовался вашей программой чтобы их получить.

Хватит ли точности `float` чтобы представить объём с точностью до третьего знака после запятой?

Чтобы проверить выведем последовательные значения типа `float`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    float x = 235702.250;
    printf("%.10f\n%.10f\n%.10f\n", nextafterf(x, x - 1), x, nextafterf(x, x + 1));
}
```

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror next.c -lm && ./a.out 
> 235702.2343750000
> 235702.2500000000
> 235702.2656250000
> ```

Разница между соседними значениеми `0.015625`. Больше одной тысячной. `float` просто не способен хранить такие числа с нужной точностью.

Заменим `float` на `double`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    double p, d;
    if (scanf("%lf %lf", &d, &p) != 2) {
        return 1;
    }
    const double s = d * d + 2 * d * sqrt(p * p - (d * d) / 4);
    const double h = sqrt(p * p - (d * d) / 2);
    const double v = d * d * h / 3;
    printf("%.3lf %.3lf\n", s, v);
}
```

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror double.c -lm 
> $ echo 100 100 | ./a.out 
> 27320.508 235702.260
> ```

Объём отличается! Проверим точность:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    double x = 235702.260;
    printf("%.20lf\n%.20lf\n%.20lf\n", nextafter(x, x - 1), x, nextafter(x, x + 1));
}
```

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror next-double.c -lm && ./a.out 
> 235702.25999999998020939529
> 235702.26000000000931322575
> 235702.26000000003841705620
> ```

Разница между последовательными значениями `2.9103830456733704e-11`. Этого достаточно чтобы представить ответ точно.

Важно понимать что число выше не означает что ответ найден с точностью до `3*10^-11`. Наоборот, это оценка снизу: ответ не может быть найден с точностью лучше чем `3*10^-11`. Реальная точность программы всегда будет ниже. Насколько ниже - предмет для анализа, который выходит за рамки этого ответа. Можно надеяться что точности `double` хватит: она на семь порядков выше нужной.

Никогда не считайте во `float` без веских причин. У вас нет точного способа оценить точность расчётов. В такой ситуации лишних разрядов не бывает.

Зачем нужен `float` если им не пользоваться?

1. Чтобы считать большие матрицы из чисел, а памяти недостаточно. Нейронные сети попадают в этот пункт.
2. Чтобы считать на очень слабом железе без аппаратной поддержки вещественной арифметики. Например, на микроконтроллере вычисления на `float` будут заметно быстрее чем на `double`.

Во всех остальных случаях только `double`.

Answer (score 3):

Исправьте `float` на `double` и вы будете приятно удивлены.

И вообще, в общем случае при вычислениях с плавающей точкой используйте `double`, а не `float`.

Comment: Я поменял,но в ответе появляются иероглифы                                                                                            #include <stdio.h>  
#include <math.h>  
int main(void)  
{  
double p,d,H,S,V;  
scanf("%le %le",&d,&p);  
S=d*d + 2*d*sqrt(p*p-(d*d)/4);  
H=sqrt(p*p - (d*d)/2);  
V=d*d*H/3;  
printf("%.3le %.3le",S,V);  
}         @Harry

Comment: `%.3lf`. Получилось?

Comment: теперь все получилось)))))))